# What does the word 「おけっ」 mean?

Tags: words

It is a situation that a guy on the ground asking another one who is climbing on a bed staircase with this sentence.

このへんでいいかな？

And he replied with this one.

おお　よかろうしっかり手｛て｝足｛あし｝をおさえて**おけっ。**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おけ is the imperative form for おく. You can ignore the っ at the end as it carries no meaning, only to show an abrupt end of the sentence.

The second sentence mean:

Oh, hold (his/her) arms and legs tightly !